# Redirects from Joomla to ExpressionEngine

Tags: redirects, redirection, detour-pro

I'm trying to create some 301 redirects from an old Joomla site to a new EE site. As you may know, Joomla URLs look something like this;

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=59&Itemid=125
```

This is obviously hitting EE's index.php. I have tried using Detour Pro but all that happens is when you hit the URL above, it just removes the index.php so i'm wondering if there is a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us the example of what the intended ee url would be to match the joomla one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out by adding the following to my .htaccess;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=44&Itemid=128$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /map? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If you're crafty, you can create some more global .htaccess rules to grab URLs for a certain form and point them to others of a certain form.